# XSLT: Strip tags within certain tag, but preserve outer tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following dummied xml file and I need to strip out the tags within TXT. I have created a stylesheet that successfully strips **all** the tags in the file, but I just want it to only strip the tags *within* the TXT block. What changes do I need to make to the XSLT to achieve this?

XML

```
<DOC>
    <ID>1234</ID>
<TXT>
<A><DESC type="PERSON">George Washington</DESC> lived in a house called <DESC type="PLACE">Mount Vernon.</DESC></A>
<A><DESC type="PERSON">Thomas Jefferson</DESC> lived in a house called <DESC type="PLACE">Monticello.</DESC></A>
</TXT>
</DOC>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="strip-tags">
        <xsl:param name="TXT"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($TXT, 'A')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$TXT"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                    <xsl:with-param name="TXT" select="substring-after($TXT, 'A')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$TXT"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    1234

    George Washington lived in a house called Mount Vernon.
    Thomas Jefferson lived in a house called Monticello.
```

Desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DOC><ID>1234</ID>

    <TXT>George Washington lived in a house called Mount Vernon.
    Thomas Jefferson lived in a house called Monticello.</TXT>
    </DOC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformulating your requeriment:

> every node is transformed into itself except those element descendant
>   of `TXT` element

Use the [identity transformation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TXT//*">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<DOC>
    <ID>1234</ID>
   <TXT>
George Washington lived in a house called Mount Vernon.
Thomas Jefferson lived in a house called Monticello.
</TXT>
</DOC>
```

Comment: Amazing, that did exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!